# IPA FILE CONFUSION. How to Make sure if my .ipa file could run in another iPhone?

Tags: ios, ios4

New to iOS. Always get the feel that, things are not straight forward in iOS. I am developing application using Xcode 4.3.3, I have been provided a iPhone device for testing purpose, I have got the development provisioning file, so that I could run the application on the device. Perfectly, till now no issues. Now my client purchased a new device, and he would like to run the application. I did the following:

In Xcode:

```
product -> Archieve
```

It opens `Organizer`, and in `Organiser`,

1. Choose  Archieve, and press "Distribute";
2. Choose *"Save For Enterprise Or ad-Hoc Deployment"*;
3. For Code Signing Identity -> I have chosen the registered name listed in that;

Now it asks to save the .ipa file in the disk. I saved.

Questions:

1. Now, is providing this .ipa file itself enough to client for testing?
2. Do I need to provide any addition file? I.e., `<something>.mobileprovision`, if so why is it required to provide?
3. Do we need to include new iPhone UID to somewhere, so that application can run in the new mobile?

Kindly provide me a direction, and too many links are really confusing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, but I suggest you create a .plist file when you chose "save for enterprise" and then upload it to your webserver and open it like: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.myserver.com/ota/myapp/appname.plist`

2&3)
If you have a iOS Developer program: Yes, A provisioning profile should be created with the device's UDID attached to the profile (app). This should be done in iTunes connect.
If you have an enterprise developer program: You don't need the device's UDID

Comment: The .ipa is enough - it can be installed via iTunes.

Comment: True, but it's much easier to create a plist and use the itms-services protocol, so you don't have to explain the user how to install a .ipa file through iTunes.

Comment: Point is you originally said no that was not everything you needed, when it can be. I see you've corrected that though. You're right, doing that is a much nicer method.

Comment: basvk, we do  not have a server. i have a only one option to send as a attachment.

Comment: You don't have anywehere you can host the ipa? You don't need an entire server. Just a place to put the .ipa and .plist. Then you only need to mail 'them' the link and they can install the app over the air.

Comment: Well you could use a DropBox public folder to host the two files, or you could just email the ipa.

Comment: we do not have, we are not supposed to have as well. :).  pointing to your comment 2&3),  if i send the ipa file to the client, do they still need to create a provisioning profile?, if so, assume they get the provision profile for the new mobile, and then how can they install?, means given, ipa file and provisioning profile, how to go forward next?

Comment: You add their device to a provisioning profile and install it in Xcode. As long as you then choose the certificate associated with that profile in your build settings, the profile will be embedded in the ipa, so all they need to do is open the ipa in iTunes, at which point they can then sync it with their device like any other app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. No, it is chosen at the build stage based on the Code Signing Build Settings for the application. Just make sure you choose the same certificate as you built with when you archive.
3. You will need to add it to the Provisioning Portal on http://developer.apple.com/ and then download the new profile. Add this to Xcode and build afterwards to include the new device.

Comment: jrtc27, But Client does not have Xcode. they do not want the source code, but the want only binary.

Comment: i did not understand the 2nd Point. how to very that ? sorry , i m very much new to iOS, Xcode Env.

Comment: Ok, if you select the project in the left bar, click on your project again in the next section and choose "Build Settings" near the top, you should be able to scroll down and get a screen like http://theruprect.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/adhocdistributionscreens2.png?w=630. Then you want to make sure that is set to one of your certificates (your developer one will work, even if not best practice) and when you click "Distribute" for the archive, choose the same certificate.